# What permission exposes the view/edit of an object's security tab in windows?

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to set up a folder access provisioning system, without giving the people who will be provisioning, domain admin accounts.

The last hurdle I've got is that I can't expose what groups control access to what folders with them- I'm looking, essentially to make this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtliW.png]

into this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlekL.png]

through AD permissions that aren't domain admin, or by giving said group read access to all folders.

Is this possible?

Comment: First - even your domain admins shouldn't have full access to the file systems - use a separate group to control access to NTFS file permissions -- segregation of duties.  Secondly, have you tried "Read Permissions"/"Change Permissions" advanced entries?

Comment: The first part of your comment is true, but there's literally nothing I can do about that particular structural decision. As far as those read/change permissions advanced entries- I have tried them, but they haven't exposed the security tab.

Comment: are you using a custom group to assign the read/change permissions permission - or a built-in group?  And is it a domain group or a group local to the file server (if applicable)?

Comment: Tried a custom group on the domain, a group local to the fileserver wouldn't be workable with our current AD policy.

Comment: At any point between the user account and the custom group in the ACL, is there a "priviledged" group -- that is one that would be affected by UAC?